# Pygame.init() not working

Tags: python, pygame, init

I downloaded pygame successfully but now when I do:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
size =  [400, 400]

pygame.display.set_mode(size)
```

it gives errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module> pygame.init AttributeError:
'module' object has no attribute 'init'
```

And nothing is working for me. Please help me use `init` and `display`.

I am using

- python 3.4.1 and
- pygame 1.9.2 on
- Windows 7 32bit and
- I installed pygame on

  ```
  c://python34/include/
  ```

Comment: How do you do it? Interpreter? Running from a file?

Answer (score 5):

You probably had named your file pygame.py
when you type:

```
import pygame
```

python won't import pygame module you want, instead it will try import local module pygame - your file. and your file hasn't method *init*.
try change file name from *pygame.py* to *mypygame.py*.

Comment: No, I named my program game.py not pygame.py and it still isn't working!!!

Comment: open python console  
type:

    import pygame

then paste output of:

    print(pygame)
    dir(pygame)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but then I reinstalled everything and realized that I had a different version of pygame than I needed for python

I realized also that I shouldn't use the .zip archive to install. I looked in there and saw that there's an installer for it if you're on any major OS. For example, for Macintosh, there's .dmg files. For Windows, there's .msi, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed your pygame library in the **include/** folder, but somehow didn't have the correct files inside it. This may of happened because of some downloading issues or the website you were downloading from. Hope this helps! You want to type downloading pygame from pygame.org instead of some other places on the web because of possible errors or changes in code.